# Tabhost does not allow button press on some tabs

Tags: android

I have a problem with the buttons in this layout.  The problem is that when I have a single tab, all of the buttons get pressed.  Once I have a new tab, only the buttons of the next tab are clickable while the buttons of the first tab aren't.  What could be the cause of this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/background_main">
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/header"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:scaleX="1.8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="80"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
            <TabHost android:id="@+id/tabhost" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout9" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TabWidget android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@android:id/tabs"></TabWidget>
                    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
                        <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/tab1">
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/row1_1">
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/row1_2">
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/row1_3">
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/row1_4">
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton13"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton14"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton15"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton16"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </ScrollView>
                        <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/scrollView2" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/tab2">
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/row2_1">
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton17"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton18"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton19"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton20"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/row2_2">
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton21"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton22"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton23"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton24"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/row2_3">
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton25"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton26"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton27"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton28"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/row2_4">
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton29"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton30"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton31"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton32"
                                        android:layout_width="235px" android:layout_height="180px"
                                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"></ImageButton>
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </ScrollView>
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab3">
                            <TextView android:text="Wings Tab" android:id="@+id/textViewWingsTab"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab4">
                            <TextView android:text="Desserts Tab" android:id="@+id/textViewDessertsTab"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab5">
                            <TextView android:text="Drinks Tab" android:id="@+id/textViewDrinksTab"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TabHost>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="95" android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="10" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7">
                    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/textin"
                            android:text="Orders \n   1)Manager's Choice Pizza \n   2)Buko Juice"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>
                    </ScrollView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="90" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout8">
                    <TextView android:text="Total Price:" android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:text="0.0" android:id="@+id/textViewTotalPrice"
                        android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5" android:id="@+id/linearLayout6">
                <Button android:text="Send Order" android:id="@+id/set"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:text="Clear Orders" android:id="@+id/buttonClearOrders"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:text="Cancel Order" android:id="@+id/buttonCancelOrder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:text="Review Order" android:id="@+id/buttonReviewOrder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the layout and it seems that I have to have the ScrollView inside the LinearLayout tab instead of what I have done that I enclosed each tab in a ScrollView.